# LuaTeX: Use some linebreak filter to access linebreak parameters used by last tex.linebreak

Tags: luatex, tex-core

How can I access linebreak parameter table used by last call to `tex.linebreak`? As per LuaTeX manual (screenshot at bottom of post), one can override linebreak parameter table values by passing a second table argument to function `tex.linebreak`. **This is handy in overriding linebreak parameter table values, though there is no way to know what values I am overriding!!!** (unless maybe if I build a table using `tex.<keyname>` using tex library, though I don't know if that's what actually gets used) That information should be available somewhere when pre_linebreak_filter is called, and the merged values should be available when linebreak filter is called or when post_linebreak_filter is called. I would want to get and print both the default <sup>[1]</sup> linebreak parameter table being passed to `tex.linebreak` and the (finalized) merged table that actually gets used. Ideally I would not want to add any macro to my input text or vbox.

<sup>[1]</sup> default parameter table values can be different for each call to `tex.linebreak`, and afaik they can be affected by usual macros like `\centering`.

> Are the values that can be overriden using tex.linebreak's second argument the only ones that actually affect how that paragraph will get shaped? Put another way, lets say I store these parameters, and reuse them for another paragraph, is it good enough a subset of tex state to get that new paragraph have same linebreak properties as the old one? Or will I have to save and restore a whole lot more of tex properties? (note I just care about linebreak behavior)

Here's the minimal code (table values would differ for two paragraphs because of `\centering`), screenshot of output, and screenshot of definition of `tex.linebreak` from LuaTeX manual:

Code: (all you might need to do is uncomment, and fill in one line below first NOTE)

```latex
>>> lualatex linebreakparameters.tex
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
    grabbedparameters = {}
    function grabparameters (h)
        % NOTE: Uncomment the following line, and fill in the right hand side
        % thats all that is needed!
        %grabbedparameters = <add path to linebreak parameters>
        for i,v in pairs(grabbedparameters) do
            texio.write_nl(i .. '    ' .. v)
        end
        return h
    end
}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{This an equation $x=a+b^2$  without any intrinsic meaning unless one sees some. \textbf{And this is some bold text to add some variety to this piece of text.} And am typing here,  difference diffierence $b=c^3$. This is random text without any meaning, though it is being presented here to aid this communication.}

% NOTE: If necessary replace pre_ with post_
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter', grabparameters, 'grab and print tex.linebreak parameters')}

\setbox0 = \vbox{{\hsize=3in\relax\sampletext\par\vspace*{1cm}\centering\sampletext\par}}

\box0

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Screenshots from LuaTeX manual:

[image: Screenshot showing definition of method tex dot linebreak]
[image: Second screenshot that shows remaining part of tex dot linebreak's definition]

Comment: I don't think there is a table other than dynamically to generate the named argument interface in this call, they are just the values `tex.leftskip` etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, are these the only parameters worth saving, and reusing? As you can see above in excerpt from the manual, “the *understood* parameters are as follows”

Comment: as far as I know they are the ones used by the standard linebreak but of course if you are replacing that with your own lua code it could use anything